# Connect windows 11 to sql server 2000

Tags: encryption, sql-server-2000, windows-11

I am, !!!finally!!!, migrating my windows ecosystem to windows 11 and sql latest versions.
But meanwhile I already have pcs with windows 11 and sql 2000 is still around and they don't like each other :-/

Excel to SQL, Excel to analisys Services, access to SQL all work great in up to windows 10 but fail in windows 11.

I get all sort of errors related with, I suppose, encryption. Any way to solve this?

I know that odbc 18 changed the default encryption to YES, but, as far as I can see, odbc 11 is installed.

[access connect error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKvx1.png)

I already tried activating SSL 3 and TLS 1 in control panel, but doesn't work.

thanks,
Cláudio

Answer (score 0):

after battling the same problem today, I figured out that it was related to Windows 11 Update 2022H2, which I had installed on my machine last week.
Microsoft lists a known issue in regards to TLS/SSL handshakes, which was presumably fixed in an optional update here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-health/status-windows-11-22h2#2924msgdesc

I was unable to install the patch, which is supposed to fix the problem (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/october-25-2022-kb5018496-os-build-22621-755-preview-64040bea-1e02-4b6d-bad1-b036200c2cb3) and thus opted to just revert to the previous build for the time being. It instantly fixed the issue.

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The issue for me was that Win 11 22H2 removed cipher suites that are apparently required. I got the tip from https://danarman.blogspot.com/2023/02/windows-11-unable-to-connect-to-sql.html to put the pre-22H2 list back in the registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Cryptography\Configuration\SSL\00010002`, value `Functions`.

I found the original Windows 11 list at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/tls-cipher-suites-in-windows-11 copied the table out of the web page and built this for the `Functions` value:

```
TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
```

You must reboot for the change to take effect.

Comment: This will work, but it's a **bad idea**. The old cipher suites were removed for **important reasons**. Putting them back will let them to work for more than just SQL Server, and leave the entire system vulnerable to TLS downgrade attacks. A better plan is working harder on getting off of SQL Server 2000, which is formally end of life. This means it no longer gets _any_ updates... _not even critical security patches_, for which there are several open critical-rated CVEs. Or, since the needed ciphers are weak anyway, you'll be just as well off disabling encryption on the SQL Server end entirely.

Comment: It looks like the solution to my problem, yes!
But I already solved the problem in the correct way: bye bye SQL 2000 :)

Answer (score -2):

Connect from Windows 11 to mssql 2000
get list database get driver version get version mssql 2000

1. Get Driver from Directory \LIB from this archive  https://www.akadia.com/download/documents/sqlsrv_jdbc.tar.gz
2. Text APP.java
3. Good Luck

package org.example; import java.sql.*; /** * Microsoft SQL Server 2000 JDBC test program FROM WINDOWS 11 * public class App { public App() throws Exception { // Get connection DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver()); Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://IPMSSQLSERVER2000:1433", "LOGIN", "PASS"); if (connection != null) { System.out.println(); System.out.println("Successfully connected"); System.out.println(); // Meta data DatabaseMetaData meta = connection.getMetaData(); System.out.println("Driver Information"); System.out.println("\tDriver Name: "+ meta.getDriverName()); System.out.println("\tDriver Version: "+ meta.getDriverVersion()); System.out.println("\nDatabase Information "); System.out.println("\tDatabase Name: "+ meta.getDatabaseProductName()); System.out.println("\tDatabase Version: "+ meta.getDatabaseProductVersion()); // Select some data - database name list Statement select = connection.createStatement(); ResultSet result = select.executeQuery("use master\n" + "\n" + "\n" + "create table ##dbtable(dbname varchar(100),tablename varchar(1000))\n" + "\n" + " \n" + "\n" + "exec sp_MSforeachdb 'USE [?]; declare @dbid int;set @dbid= db_id(); if @dbid not in(1,2,3,4) insert into ##dbtable select TABLE_CATALOG dbName,TABLE_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES '\n" + "\n" + "select dbname from ##dbtable group by dbname"); while (result.next()) { System.out.println(result.getString(1)); } } } public static void main (String args[]) throws Exception { App app = new App(); } }

Comment: Please format this answer. It's extremely difficult to see what this is saying with the giant wall of text at the end.